# k8s-visualizer for Kubernetes in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to run k8s-visualizer for Kubernetes in der Google Cloud Platform. Just found how to run it local.

How to run it in the Google Cloud Platform?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [k8s-visualizer](https://github.com/saturnism/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer.git) is written in a way that it depends on the `kubectl proxy` and runs all Ajax calls against `/api/...`. It isn't ready to run on the cluser.

If you want to have it on your cluster, you'd have to fork the existing code and adjust all API calls slightly to hit the apiserver.

Once this is done, wrap everything into a container and deploy it into a Pod along with a service.

A good starting point are the [open pull requests](https://github.com/saturnism/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer/pull/3)

Cheers

Comment: sounds like a good solution. I am going to give it a try. I'll inform you if it is working. Thanks @pagid!